# In this case it makes sense to insert a primary key for mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, primary-key

Hi guys I hope you can let me know if in this case it makes sense insert a primary key in my mysql table and if there are too many 6 indices!

Basically I would like to create a table with all earthquakes that have occurred in the world since 1900 to date (there are about one million records).

Each record is made up of:

- Date of quake in milliseconds
- Latitude
- Longitude
- Magnitude
- Depth
- Source Data (usgs,emsc ecc)
- Region where occured
- Serial number (that i use for other things)

This is how i would create table in `MySql`:

```
CREATE TABLE earthquakes (
  milliseconds BIGINT,
  latitude FLOAT,
  longitude FLOAT,
  magnitude FLOAT,
  depth FLOAT,
  source VARCHAR(2),
  region SMALLINT,
  serial VARCHAT(16)
);
```

In my website i have two pages where could send query to database:

1. *Earthquake history* => where an user can be extrapolate earthquakes by **date**, **latitude and longitude**, **magnitude** and eventually also for **depth**.
2. *More Details about earthquake* => In this case there are two query: first by **Serial number** (that is unique so refers to the single earthquake of the page more details) and then a query by **date**, **latitude and longitude**, **magnitude**.

---

**UPDATE**

This is an example record

```
12345678901112145,-35.4905,167.7843,7.5,450.4,'E',134,'2017-01-10-134'
```

**END UPDATE**

---

I don't know what quake is at third position or for example al first position and besides i have a php that each 2 minutes adds new earthquakes in this table.

So can you explain why in this case i should add a `PRIMARY KEY` and if is correct how i would use indexes in my table ? 
What would you do in my case ?

I hope can help me.... sorry for my english :)

Comment: Thank you for comment but is not very useful

Comment: In this case could you provide an example on those serial numbers which are generated in the website?, and behavior of generated serial ?(random or not) since a primary key function is to make sure a record in database is Unique, and disable another record that is inserted on same value

Comment: A primary key is a basic concept in a relational database design. It's the proper way to uniquely identify a record. I can't think of any scenario when you would *not* want one.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález All experts and none are able to explain the utility to a neophyte by making an example? Anyone who can tell me if I might use the "serial" field as a primary key? and if is correct how use indexes in my code...

Comment: If you don't have a primary key, the only way to do anything with a given row (fetch, update, delete...) is to filter by every column in the table (`WHERE milliseconds=? AND latitude=? AND [...] serial=?`). And even then nothing prevents the table from having more than one identical rows.

Comment: well someone gave you an answer below and someone upvoted it and haven't yet responded to your comment and saying that @GordonLinoff 's comment is not very useful, well I'm sure he knows what he's talking about here, given his experience and knowledge.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The most experienced users (with a higher reputation) are very strict and unavailable even when the question is very articulated and the user (inexperienced) has more doubts ... who has knowledge should share it, especially if a user (Not English) asks for help here. Sometimes it seems too important to vote!

Comment: i think i might suggest you to use primary key since its unique number ,since it will also prevents you trouble from identical serial, which you might add some conditions and looping to check same data in database on your PHP code

Answer (score 0):

Use the first row or entry in your database. Name it "id", set it to "int", make it's length whatever you feel you need, set it to "primary" and set it to "autoincrement". This will create unique id's for each entry which you can then use for many SQL queries and functions.